# IntersectionObserver - run only when above a certain screen width

Tags: javascript

```js
if ( ('IntersectionObserver' in window) && (!document.documentElement.classList.contains('dont-sticky')) ) {
    var body = document.body
    const sentinel = document.getElementById('sentinel')
    const stickyEl = document.querySelector('.test')
    const stickyClass = "sticky"
    const handler = (entries) => {
        if (stickyEl) {
            if (!entries[0].isIntersecting) {
                body.classList.add(stickyClass);
                return false;
            } else {
                body.classList.remove(stickyClass);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    const observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(handler)
    observer.observe(sentinel)
}
```

```css
body { height: 4000px; background: white; }
body.sticky { background: #FFC; }
.test { width: 100%; height :100px; top: auto; position: relative; background: #FCF; }
body.sticky .test { top: -1px; position: sticky; background: #F6F; }
```

```html
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>
<p>text text text</p>

<div id="sentinel"></div>

<div class="test"></div>
```

I am playing with IntersectionObserver to add a class to the body element when the .test item is position:sticky.

Ideally I would like the stickyClass to only be added to the body element when the screen width is greater than 1000px wide, including allowing for browser window resizing when viewing the page.

I know I can write css media queries to neutralize the sticky related changes when 999px width or under - but I am interested to know if it's possible and also how best to implement a 1000px minimum window width with the IntersectionObserver script. I am interested to see various ways to do it.

One option I found was window.innerWidth, which works well in the first page load but does not take into account browser width resizing.

```
window.innerWidth >= 1000

//used like so in the top line of the script

if ( ('IntersectionObserver' in window) && (window.innerWidth >= 1000) && (!document.documentElement.classList.contains('dont-sticky')) ) {
```

In searching the web I can see a new option called ResizeObserver and also something called Match. I am unsure if these are the current way to do it and also how to implement these with my IntersectionObserver script.

Greatly appreciate any help.

(confirming that I am an absolute rookie at javascript)

Many thanks.

Comment: "_does not take into account browser width resizing._" - I don't see code for the `window.resize` event to capture the resize. Did you add that?

Comment: I am not sure how to implement the resizing with the IntersectionObserver code. The single use `&& (window.innerWidth >= 1000)` was as far I got and why I need help from someone much better at javascript than me :)

Comment: `intersectionObserver` doesn't respond to `window.resize` events. You have to write an event handler: `window.addEventHandler('resize', ()=>{ /* apply styles here */ })` [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event#addeventlistener_equivalent) - that isn't something you can do with `intersectionObserver` - Look at the list at the top of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) the describes the things you can do with it.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info Randy, appreciate it.